# ODE does not verify on direct back substitution

Tags: differential-equations

```
Clear["`.*"]
r1=1;smax=8.;
ONEONE
Hd=-0.25;
EQU1={PH'[s]+Cos[PH[s]]/R[s]==2 Hd,PH[0]==0.,R'[s]==Sin[PH[s]],R[0]==r1,Z'[s]==Cos[PH[s]],Z[0]==0};
NDSolve[EQU1,{PH,R,Z},{s,0,smax}];
{r[u_],z[u_]}={R[u],Z[u]}/.First[%];
CHK=Plot[{ph'[s]+Cos[ph[s]]/r[s]-2 Hd},{s,0,smax},GridLines->Automatic,PlotLabel->"ODEchk1"]
h1=ParametricPlot[{z[s],r[s]},{s,0,smax},AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Red,PlotLabel->"HALF DIFF ",GridLines->Automatic]
TWOTWO
Hd=-0.75;
EQU2={PH'[s]+Cos[PH[s]]/R[s]==2 Hd,PH[0]==0.,R'[s]==Sin[PH[s]],R[0]==r1,Z'[s]==Cos[PH[s]],Z[0]==0};
NDSolve[EQU2,{PH,R,Z},{s,0,smax}];
{r[u_],z[u_]}={R[u],Z[u]}/.First[%];
CHK=Plot[{ph'[s]+Cos[ph[s]]/r[s]-2Hd},{s,0,smax},GridLines->Automatic,PlotLabel->"ODEchk2"]
h2=ParametricPlot[{z[s],r[s]},{s,0,smax},AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Magenta,PlotLabel->"HALF DIFF ",GridLines->Automatic]
THREETHREE
Hd=-1.; smax=3.14
EQU3={PH'[s]+Cos[PH[s]]/R[s]==2 Hd,PH[0]==0.,R'[s]==Sin[PH[s]],R[0]==r1,Z'[s]==Cos[PH[s]],Z[0]==0};
NDSolve[EQU3,{PH,R,Z},{s,0,smax}];
{r[u_],z[u_],ph[u_]}={R[u],Z[u],PH[u]}/.First[%];
CHK=Plot[{ph'[s]+Cos[ph[s]]/r[s]-2Hd},{s,0,smax},GridLines->Automatic,PlotLabel->"ODEchk3"]
h3=ParametricPlot[{z[s],r[s]},{s,0,smax},AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue,PlotLabel->"HALF DIFF",GridLines->Automatic]
Show[{h1,h2,h3},PlotRange->All,AspectRatio->1.1]
```

There no direct tally on back checking first two cases for $Hd=-0.25,-0.75$. Some times a large number appears and sometimes nothing at all. Third case tally is okay.

Thanks for error pointers.

Comment: ``Clear["`.*"]`` doesn't do anything (why do you have a `.` in there?) There is almost no text in your post and the code is very hard to read. Please explain the problem in details and make the example as small as reasonable.  Comment the code where needed.

Comment: Thanks.thought it might work like Clear[All]

Comment: Maybe you tried to use regexes? In Mathematica it would just be `*`, not `.*` (it's a not a regex, just a wildcard)

Comment: So should it be,  Clear["`*,"] or Clear["*,"] ?

Comment: They're the same, but the comma is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `NDSolve`to `NDSolveValue`!

Try

```
r1 = 1;
smax = {8., 3.14}[[ 1]];
Hd = {-0.25, -.75, -1}[[1]];
EQU1 = {PH'[s] + Cos[PH[s]]/R[s] == 2 Hd, PH[0] == 0.,R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]], R[0] ==r1, Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]], Z[0] == 0} 
{ph, r, z} = NDSolveValue[EQU1, {PH, R, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
CHK = Plot[{ph'[s] + Cos[ph[s]]/r[s] - 2 Hd}, {s, 0, smax}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "ODEchk1"]
h1 = ParametricPlot[{z[s], r[s]}, {s, 0, smax}, AspectRatio -> 1,PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> "HALF DIFF ", GridLines -> Automatic]
```

which evaluates for all given parameter pairs.

[image]

Comment: Schoenen Dank !

Comment: @Narasimham Bitte schön!

Comment: Added one line of analytical (closed form) solution slopeCHK in code .It tallies for some Hd values and does not tally for entire domain on arc length $s$  for other values of Hd. Can you please check the expression for a few cases? There is a running thread in MO.

Comment: @Narasimham If you know the analytical solution(Why didn't you share this knowledge?)  you could compare directly with `{ph, r, z}`

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354531/constant-curvature-difference-surfaces/354624#354624

Comment: $\cosϕ=r/r1−2Hd\,rlog(r/r1) $ ; Reference MO thread above (second line): $dr=ds\,sinϕ,dz=ds\,cosϕ;r=∫sinϕ\,ds,z=∫cosϕ\,ds $

Comment: slopeCHK =   Plot[Cos[ph[s]]/r[s] - 1/r1 + 2 Hd Log[r[s]/r1], {s, 0, smax}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "SLOPEchk"]       This should be zero, but plots to a constant. @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: It plots stepwice constant. Sorry, you should check your analytical solution.

Comment: The solution could be entirely wrong, but cannot be correct stepwise..below $r=0$ the  solution may be not valid.

Comment: So I used second order ODE (link}

Comment: @Narasimham Sorry I don't have time to check all the links. But if I differentiate the condition `D[-Cos[\[Phi][s]] + R[s]/r1 - 2 Hd R[s] Log[R[s]/r1],s]` and substitude the ode-expressions `\[Phi][s]`,R'[s]`  I get an expression different to zero!?

Comment: Thanks,the matter is now fully settled, there is a sign error. The following works:     Plot[-Cos[ph[s]] + r[s]/r1 + 2 Hd r[s] Log[r[s]/r1], {s, 0, smax}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "SLOPEchkNew", 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]